# how to make cdn server ubuntu system

Tags: cdn

I am searching for a software that can be use for setup CDN Server on ubuntu system i also have tried [Squid Cache](http://www.squid-cache.org/) but unable to setup it please anybody suggess me software that can be used for make CDN server on my ubuntu system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Ubuntu OpenStack cloud you can download it from here [Ubuntu OpenStack](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud)

Answer (score 1):

Squid Cache is a caching system it is not proper CDN system try to use [OpenCdn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencdn/files/opencdn/) it should be helpfull for make cdn server you can get detail information and documentation on [labtel.ing.uniroma1.it](http://labtel.ing.uniroma1.it/opencdn/docs.html)